# Progress bar in r and system time

Tags: r

Computation time is hugely different when I use progress bar in the following code. Any suggestion to improve it would be greatly appreciated.

```
   mysum = function(n){
   s=0
   total=length(a)
   for (i in 1: n){
   s = s+i
   pb = txtProgressBar(min = 0, max=n, initial = 0, style = 3) 
   setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
 }
close(pb)
s
}

system.time(mysum(10000))        


user  system elapsed 
1.828   0.158   1.871


mysum1 = function(n){
s=0
total=length(a)
for (i in 1: n){
s = s+i
}
s
}

system.time(mysum1(10000))       


user  system elapsed 
0.003   0.000   0.003
```

I am using R 3.2.4 through R Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress bars create overhead. The question you should ask is the overhead created by the progress bar worth the extra time it takes to show you where you are in your calculations. In most of my calculations it is worth it since they may take minutes and the progress bar adds only a litlle bit of extra time but a lot of information.

Also there are more packages that use a progress bar that works a bit faster than the `txtProgressBar` function.

Below are some comparisons. The first function is without a progress bar. You can see that the progress bar from the package progress is a bit faster than the one from the base R. There are some more progress bars around, like pbapply. And on the Github page of progress you can find a rcpp example.

```
mysum0 <- function(n){
  s <- 0
  for (i in 1: n){
    s = s + i
  }
  s
}

mysum1 = function(n){
  s=0
    for (i in 1: n){
    s = s + i
    pb = txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = n, initial = 0, style = 3) 
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  }
  close(pb)
  s
}

library(progress)
mysum2 <- function(n){
  pb <- progress_bar$new(total = n, clear = FALSE)
  s <- 0
  pb$tick(0)
    for (i in 1: n){
    s <- s + i
    pb$tick()
  }
  s
}

mb <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark(mysum0(1000),
                               mysum1(1000),
                               mysum2(1000),
                               times = 100L)

pirnt(mb)
print(mb, unit = "eps")
print(mb, unit = "relative")

> mb
Unit: microseconds
         expr        min          lq        mean     median         uq        max neval
 mysum0(1000)    272.091    288.4745    319.0893    297.252    307.492   2108.846   100
 mysum1(1000) 121191.322 124239.9035 125913.9429 125777.652 127380.937 133798.170   100
 mysum2(1000)  76761.331  80152.6575  82717.5762  81554.361  83240.735 132357.554   100
> print(mb, unit = "eps") # how iterations test per second
Unit: evaluations per second
         expr        min          lq        mean     median          uq         max neval
 mysum0(1000) 474.192995 3252.120061 3307.531315 3364.14894 3466.514469 3675.241004   100
 mysum1(1000)   7.473944    7.850468    7.945014    7.95054    8.048948    8.251416   100
 mysum2(1000)   7.555292   12.013414   12.151598   12.26176   12.476193   13.027393   100
> print(mb, unit = "relative") # relative to the first function tested
Unit: relative
         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 mysum0(1000)   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000   1.0000  1.00000   100
 mysum1(1000) 445.4073 430.6790 394.6041 423.1348 414.2577 63.44615   100
 mysum2(1000) 282.1164 277.8501 259.2302 274.3610 270.7086 62.76302   100
```

Comment: Thanks. It was very helpful. +1