# R progress bar based on number of seconds given

Tags: r, progress-bar

I am creating a function to be used by different user. Since the function is long I would like to create a progress bar based on the number of second (estimated by me) in order to bring confidence to the user that the code is working. My proposal (based on an answer found on stakoverflow). The problem is that I do not know how to convert this '200000' into seconds. Any help?

```
library(progress)


  total <- 200000
  # create progress bar
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = total, style = 3)
  for(i in 1:total){
    # update progress bar
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  }
  close(pb)
```

Comment: Think the two answers you got are what you are looking for. I'd like to add that `progress_bar()` seems to be faster than `txtProgressBar()` from utils (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519353/progress-bar-in-r-and-system-time). But doesn't this implementation sort of defeat the purpose of a progress bar, I mean it is tracking time, not progress.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, using `Sys.sleep`. This will go for 7 seconds.

```r
library(progress)

secs <- 7
pb <- progress_bar$new(total = secs)
for (i in 1:secs) {
  pb$tick()
  Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

Set `secs` as required.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe? If you want the bar to be updated only once per second, simply remove the *2 (two places) and replace .5 with 1 in Sys.sleep().

```
start_pb <- function(secs) {
  # create progress bar
  pb <- txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = secs*2, style = 3)
  for(i in 1:(secs*2)) {
    # update progress bar
    Sys.sleep(.5)
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
  }
  close(pb)
}

start_pb(20)
```